# How to make parallel curves in three.js for road marking?

Tags: javascript, three.js, bezier, curve

I´m trying to draw some **parallel** curved lines, one next to other, but if I separate them by modifying/translating their position in one axis, the result is not what I am looking for.

Code is simple, a bezier to make the central path and clones with other material for the sides.

```
var bezier = new THREE.CubicBezierCurve3(
                new THREE.Vector3(initx, inity, 0),
                new THREE.Vector3(cp1x, cp1y, 0),
                new THREE.Vector3( cp2x, cp2y, 0),
                new THREE.Vector3(finalx, finaly, 0)
                );

var curvePath = new THREE.CurvePath();
curvePath.add(bezier);

var path = curvePath.createPointsGeometry( 5 );
path.computeLineDistances();

var lineMat = new THREE.LineDashedMaterial({ color: 0xFFFFFF,
                                             dashSize: 3,
                                             gapSize: 2, 
                                             linewidth: 10});

var curveLine = new THREE.Line(path, lineMat);

curveLine.rotation.set(-Math.PI/2,0,0);
curveLine.position.y = 0.1;

var leftLine = curveLine.clone();
leftLine.material = matLine;

var rightLine = curveLine.clone();
rightLine.material = matLine;

leftLine.translateX(-3.5);
rightLine.position.set(3.5,0,0);

scene.add(curveLine);
scene.add(leftLine);
curveLine.add(rightLine);
```

This is the result:
[image]

And this are some examples of what I am looking for:

[image: d][image: source: https://pomax.github.io/bezierjs/][image: source: https://pomax.github.io/bezierjs/]

Last two images are from [Bezier.js](https://pomax.github.io/bezierjs/) library.

I think that applying an **offset** to the curved line, **or** drawing another line **using the normals** of the first one might be the solution, but I can't find anything useful to do it in the documentation. 
I think that it could also be done drawing a line from a distance of the tangent axis or something like that, but it may be a easier way, any ideas?

I had a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039841/how-to-draw-parallel-line-using-three-js) but its for straight lines.

Comment: There is a code pen with working example [here](https://codepen.io/brunoimbrizi/pen/VYEWgY). Explanations are [here](http://brunoimbrizi.com/unbox/2015/03/offset-curve/). Many of the vector2 additions on the codepen are already available as part of three.js.

Comment: @Radio That's awesome.

Comment: @Radio That is really great, but I was looking for a simpler "native" way to do it with three.js, although I will have a look and try to solve it making the operations like that.

Comment: you'll want to read up on http://www.redblobgames.com/articles/curved-paths/ -- and as the creator of those last two images you show, I would absolutely advocate using offset curves. I doubt three.js has this built in, but then you don't need to use "just three.js", you can use something like bezier.js to get the offset curves you need, and then simply feed the coordinates found by offsetting back into three.js so it can do the drawing for you.

Comment: Thank you @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I added the source of the images on its description, but now I see it is not enough, so I've just added the source on a separated line.

Comment: yeah so again: use bezier.js (or anything else that can do offsetting) to *compute* the offset curves properly, then use three.js to *draw* the result. In the case of bezier.js, you get a set of curves back, because [you can't generally offset a bezier with just one other bezier](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#offsetting)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end, I did it by myself.

I calculated the **tangent** and the **normal** of the main curve on its points using **getTangent() and rotating it 90 degrees** to obtain the normal. I created more vertices for that normal multiplying its values by a scalar. Then I  **got the point I wanted from the normals in world coordinates and connect** them creating a CatmullRomCurve3 Geometry:

```
for(var i = 0.0; i <= 1.0; i += 0.2){

    var point = curvePath.getPointAt(i);

    var tangent = curvePath.getTangent(i);
    var extension1 = new THREE.Vector3(tangent.x*2, tangent.y*2, 0);
    var extension2 = new THREE.Vector3(extension1.x*2, extension1.y*2, 0);

    var tangentGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    tangentGeometry.vertices.push(tangent, extension1, extension2);

    var tangentLine = new THREE.Line(tangentGeometry,greenMaterial);
    tangentLine.position.set(point.x, point.y, point.z);

    normal.updateMatrixWorld(); // VERY IMPORTANT

    var normal = tangentLine.clone();
    normal.rotateZ(Math.PI/2);

    var normalLastVertex = normal.geometry.vertices[2].clone();
    normalLastVertex.applyMatrix4(normal.matrixWorld); //convert to world coords.

    pointsArray.push(normalLastVertex); //for using them out of the loop

    curveLine.add(tangentLine);
    curveLine.add(normal);
}
```

Here I have last normals vertices in the points array, so I have to create the spline connecting them out of the loop.

```
    var splineCurveOffsetLeft = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3([

       new THREE.Vector3((pointsArray[0].x), pointsArray[0].y, 0),
       new THREE.Vector3((pointsArray[1].x), pointsArray[1].y, 0),
       new THREE.Vector3((pointsArray[2].x), pointsArray[2].y, 0),
       new THREE.Vector3((pointsArray[3].x), pointsArray[3].y, 0),
       new THREE.Vector3((pointsArray[4].x), pointsArray[4].y, 0),
       new THREE.Vector3((pointsArray[5].x), pointsArray[5].y, 0)           
    ]);
splineCurveOffsetLeft.type = 'catmullrom';
splineCurveOffsetLeft.closed = false;

var offsetGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
offsetGeometry.vertices = splineCurveOffsetLeft.getPoints(6);

var offsetLine = new THREE.Line(offsetGeometry, cyanMaterial);

offsetLine.rotation.set(-Math.PI/2, 0, 0);
offsetLine.position.y=0.1;

scene.add(offsetLine);
```

I made the same for the other offset line just inverting its rotation and this is the result:

[image: Offset curve]

Green = Tangents, Red = Normals, Cyan = Parallel curve

Comment: since you are only ever rotating around the Z I would think this only works for 2d curves?

Comment: That is correct. Thank you for the appointment, no vertical adjusts made here, only plane curves.

Comment: Best things in life you do by yourself! You can never rely on anyone. Especially not on SO.