# How to draw parallel rectangles with rubber-band in canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw a group of shapes using canvas.

I have referenced below SO threads:

[Draw a parallel line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825412/draw-a-parallel-line)
[How to draw parallel line using three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039841/how-to-draw-parallel-line-using-three-js)

but not able to figure out how to calculate points for the rectangles parallel in as we stretch the line.

Any reference for stretching shapes with canvas is appreciated.

```js
//Canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
//Variables
var canvasx = $(canvas).offset().left;
var canvasy = $(canvas).offset().top;
var last_mousex = last_mousey = 0;
var mousex = mousey = 0;
var mousedown = false;

  // grid parameters
  var gridSpacing = 20; // pixels
  var gridWidth = 1;
  //var gridColor = "#f1f1f1";
  var gridColor = "lightgray";
  /** */
    var originX = 0;

    /** */
    var originY = 0;
 drawGrid();
//Mousedown
$(canvas).on('mousedown', function(e) {
    last_mousex = parseInt(e.clientX-canvasx);
 last_mousey = parseInt(e.clientY-canvasy);
    mousedown = true;
});

//Mouseup
$(canvas).on('mouseup', function(e) {
    mousedown = false;
});

//Mousemove
$(canvas).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    mousex = parseInt(e.clientX-canvasx);
 mousey = parseInt(e.clientY-canvasy);
    if(mousedown) {    
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); //clear canvas
        drawGrid();
        ctx.setLineDash([5, 15]);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(last_mousex,last_mousey);
        ctx.lineTo(mousex,mousey);
        //ctx.lineTo(mousex,mousey);
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
        ctx.lineDashOffset = 2;
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';       
        ctx.stroke();
        
        startx = last_mousex;
        starty = last_mousey;
        drawPolygon([last_mousex, mousex, mousex, last_mousex, last_mousex],  
                    [last_mousey-10, mousey-10, mousey-60, last_mousey-60],true, 'gray', false, 'black', 2);
        
        drawPolygon([last_mousex, mousex, mousex, last_mousex, last_mousex],  
                    [last_mousey+10, mousey+10, mousey+60, last_mousey+60],true, 'gray', false, 'black', 2);
        
        
        
    }
    //Output
    $('#output').html('current: '+mousex+', '+mousey+'<br/>last: '+last_mousex+', '+last_mousey+'<br/>mousedown: '+mousedown);
});

/** */
    function drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY, width, color) {
      // width is an integer
      // color is a hex string, i.e. #ff0000
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
      ctx.lineTo(endX, endY);
      ctx.lineWidth = width;
      ctx.strokeStyle = color;
      ctx.stroke();
    }


function drawPolygon(xArr, yArr, fill, fillColor, stroke, strokeColor, strokeWidth) {
      // fillColor is a hex string, i.e. #ff0000
      fill = fill || false;
      stroke = stroke || false;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(xArr[0], yArr[0]);
      for (var i = 1; i < xArr.length; i++) {
        ctx.lineTo(xArr[i], yArr[i]);
      }
      ctx.closePath();
      if (fill) {
        ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;
        ctx.fill();
      }
      if (stroke) {
        ctx.lineWidth = strokeWidth;
        ctx.strokeStyle = strokeColor;
        ctx.stroke();
      }
      //console.log(xArr);
      //console.log(yArr);
      
    }
    
    /** returns n where -gridSize/2 < n <= gridSize/2  */
    function calculateGridOffset(n) {
      if (n >= 0) {
        return (n + gridSpacing / 2.0) % gridSpacing - gridSpacing / 2.0;
      } else {
        return (n - gridSpacing / 2.0) % gridSpacing + gridSpacing / 2.0;
      }
    }

    /** */
    function drawGrid() {
      var offsetX = calculateGridOffset(-originX);
      var offsetY = calculateGridOffset(-originY);
      var width = canvas.width;
      var height = canvas.height;
      for (var x = 0; x <= (width / gridSpacing); x++) {
        drawLine(gridSpacing * x + offsetX, 0, gridSpacing * x + offsetX, height, gridWidth, gridColor);
      }
      for (var y = 0; y <= (height / gridSpacing); y++) {
        drawLine(0, gridSpacing * y + offsetY, width, gridSpacing * y + offsetY, gridWidth, gridColor);
      }
    }
```

```css
canvas {
    cursor: crosshair;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference link but I need some help for correcting parallel rectangle start and end point offset correction.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you really wanted to know how to fix your canvas 2D code, NOT how to use three.js. (three.js is a 3d library but your code is using canvas 2d). Sorry if I guessed wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is what you wanted.

Instead of trying to manually draw your line rotated, instead, move the origin of the canvas to the start of the line,

```
    // save the canvas state
    ctx.save();

    // move origin to start of line
    ctx.translate(last_mousex, last_mousey);
```

then rotate the origin so it points toward the end of the line in the positive X direction

```
    // compute direction of line from start to end
    const dx = mousex - last_mousex;
    const dy = mousey - last_mousey;
    const angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

    // rotate to point to end of line
    ctx.rotate(angle);
```

then compute the length of the line from the start to the end

```
    // compute length of line
    const length = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
```

and just draw an arrow in the positive x direction of that length

```
    ctx.setLineDash([5, 15]);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(length, 0);
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.lineDashOffset = 2;
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';       
    ctx.stroke();
    drawPolygon([0, length, length, 0, 0],  
                [-10, -10, -60, -60],true, 'gray', false, 'black', 2);

    drawPolygon([0, length, length, 0, 0],  
                [+10, +10, +60, +60],true, 'gray', false, 'black', 2);

    // restore the canvas state
    ctx.restore();
```

while we're at it your code for calculating the mouse position didn't work if the page is scrolled. This will get the mouse position relative to the pixels in the canvas.

```
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  mousex = (e.clientX - rect.left) * canvas.width  / canvas.clientWidth;
  mousey = (e.clientY - rect.top ) * canvas.height / canvas.clientHeight;
```

```js
//Canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
//Variables
var last_mousex = last_mousey = 0;
var mousex = mousey = 0;
var mousedown = false;

  // grid parameters
  var gridSpacing = 20; // pixels
  var gridWidth = 1;
  //var gridColor = "#f1f1f1";
  var gridColor = "lightgray";
  /** */
    var originX = 0;

    /** */
    var originY = 0;
 drawGrid();
//Mousedown
$(canvas).on('mousedown', function(e) {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  last_mousex = (e.clientX - rect.left) * canvas.width  / canvas.clientWidth;
 last_mousey = (e.clientY - rect.top ) * canvas.height / canvas.clientHeight;
    mousedown = true;
});

//Mouseup
$(canvas).on('mouseup', function(e) {
    mousedown = false;
});

//Mousemove
$(canvas).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  mousex = (e.clientX - rect.left) * canvas.width  / canvas.clientWidth;
 mousey = (e.clientY - rect.top ) * canvas.height / canvas.clientHeight;
    if(mousedown) {    
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); //clear canvas
        drawGrid();
        // save the canvas state
        ctx.save();

        // move origin to start of line
        ctx.translate(last_mousex, last_mousey);

        // compute direction of line from start to end
        const dx = mousex - last_mousex;
        const dy = mousey - last_mousey;
        const angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
        // rotate to point to end of line
        ctx.rotate(angle);

        // compute length of line
        const length = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

        ctx.setLineDash([5, 15]);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(length, 0);
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
        ctx.lineDashOffset = 2;
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';       
        ctx.stroke();
        drawPolygon([0, length, length, 0, 0],  
                    [-10, -10, -60, -60],true, 'gray', false, 'black', 2);
        
        drawPolygon([0, length, length, 0, 0],  
                    [+10, +10, +60, +60],true, 'gray', false, 'black', 2);

        // restore the canvas state
        ctx.restore();        
    }
    //Output
    $('#output').html('current: '+mousex+', '+mousey+'<br/>last: '+last_mousex+', '+last_mousey+'<br/>mousedown: '+mousedown);
});

/** */
    function drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY, width, color) {
      // width is an integer
      // color is a hex string, i.e. #ff0000
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
      ctx.lineTo(endX, endY);
      ctx.lineWidth = width;
      ctx.strokeStyle = color;
      ctx.stroke();
    }


function drawPolygon(xArr, yArr, fill, fillColor, stroke, strokeColor, strokeWidth) {
      // fillColor is a hex string, i.e. #ff0000
      fill = fill || false;
      stroke = stroke || false;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(xArr[0], yArr[0]);
      for (var i = 1; i < xArr.length; i++) {
        ctx.lineTo(xArr[i], yArr[i]);
      }
      ctx.closePath();
      if (fill) {
        ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;
        ctx.fill();
      }
      if (stroke) {
        ctx.lineWidth = strokeWidth;
        ctx.strokeStyle = strokeColor;
        ctx.stroke();
      }
      //console.log(xArr);
      //console.log(yArr);
      
    }
    
    /** returns n where -gridSize/2 < n <= gridSize/2  */
    function calculateGridOffset(n) {
      if (n >= 0) {
        return (n + gridSpacing / 2.0) % gridSpacing - gridSpacing / 2.0;
      } else {
        return (n - gridSpacing / 2.0) % gridSpacing + gridSpacing / 2.0;
      }
    }

    /** */
    function drawGrid() {
      var offsetX = calculateGridOffset(-originX);
      var offsetY = calculateGridOffset(-originY);
      var width = canvas.width;
      var height = canvas.height;
      for (var x = 0; x <= (width / gridSpacing); x++) {
        drawLine(gridSpacing * x + offsetX, 0, gridSpacing * x + offsetX, height, gridWidth, gridColor);
      }
      for (var y = 0; y <= (height / gridSpacing); y++) {
        drawLine(0, gridSpacing * y + offsetY, width, gridSpacing * y + offsetY, gridWidth, gridColor);
      }
    }
```

```css
canvas {
    cursor: crosshair;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
<div id="output"></div>
```